# Excel lock and grid Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I got this code I found in google. 
(http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.excel.misc/locking-cells-automatically-after/45998)
I need this for my work. -EDIT: I HAVE ZERO KNOWLEDGE IN EXCEL

All cells in the grid are not locked at the present time.
What I want to do is have the cell automatically lock after data has been 
entered.

I need to have the code working for up to Column "J" and infinite for the Rows.
This code I got in google is up to 25x25 only:
And if the cell is clear or blank, the password protection should not work and is free to type even though there's data in it before.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myIntersect As Range
    Dim myPassword As String

    myPassword = "hi there"

    With Me 'the worksheet with the code
        '25 rows by 25 columns starting in A1
        Set myRng = .Range("a1").Resize(25, 25)

        Set myIntersect = Intersect(Target, myRng)

        If myIntersect Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        .Unprotect Password:=myPassword
        For Each myCell In myIntersect.Cells
            myCell.Locked = True
        Next myCell
        .Protect Password:=myPassword
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Lock only cell or lock entire worksheet?

Comment: lock after entry in a specific cell

Comment: Try to effort before ask for help. We just help on error. Not help to make home work

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code won't work, i have test it.
Better just set default to lock it. Then made a form to change for these cells. Every click to change, it will unlock then after change it will lock itself. Isn't that more secure.
You better try your logic. from your code if found out that you DID'NT EFFORT AT ALL!. It just all copy paste from that link.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I have zero knowledge in excel. That's why I'm asking help from you guys..

Comment: From what you said "Every click to change, it will unlock then after change it will lock itself." How do you do this?

Comment: You need to make a form. Search on google. How to use VBA in Excel. After you effort. then ask again

Comment: Actually, this code works but only for up to rows/columns (25,25) only..if you exceed on that it won't work. I need to have it to work up to infinite rows. And being able not to ask for a password if the cells are cleared up.

Comment: well, infinite is a very large row number :) Perhaps you mean something like `LastRow = Cells.Find("*",SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row`

Comment: or you can just use the last number row from the excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that you don't know anything about Excel VBA, then the below sites should help you:

- Here is a tutorial site that will help you: [Excel VBA Tutorial](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-VBA-Tutorial.html)
- to learn about the Excel Object Model in VBA see

  - [MSDN Library: Super Easy Guide to the Excel Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203714%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
- to learn about working with cells and ranges in Excel VBA see

  - [MSDN Library: Working with cells & ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221536%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
  - [Excel 2003 VBA Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa272254(v=office.11).aspx)
- to learn abouut UserForms and Controls in Excel VBA see

  - [MSDN Library: UserForms in Excel VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829070)
  - [Chandoo.org: User Forms & Controls in VBA](http://chandoo.org/wp/excel-vba/user-forms/)
  - [Excel VBA Easy - Excel VBA UserForm](http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-userform-excel-vba.html)

Here are a few other websites for your reading:

- Excel MVP Site: [Contextures Excel](http://www.contextures.com/tiptech.html)
- Excel VBA Site: [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx)
- Excel MVP Site: [Ron De Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section9.htm)
- Mr Spreadsheet (John Walkenbach): [Spreadsheet Page](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tips)
- Mr Excel: [Mr Excel Site](http://www.mrexcel.com/)
- Charley Kydd Excel MVP: [Excel User dot Com](http://exceluser.com/explore/index.htm)
- McGimpsey & Associates Excel MVP Site[J.E. McGimpsey's XL Pages](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/index.html)

Best of luck

Philip